# Generate QR Code with a bigger background view

Tags: background, generator, qr-code

I want to generate some QR Code with a bigger background view, does somebody know is there an open source project can directly generate this image or can add background view to my completed QR code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Libraries generate a matrix, not an image. Some do make JPEGs, but I don't think you can specifiy the size of the background.

The border you're talking about is the quietzone, it should be 4 modules wide. Denso Wave used to indicate that in its website but I can't find much more that this: https://www.denso-wave.com/en/adcd/QRdeCODE/product.html. Yet, the specifications are clear about it.

You could use a library such as [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) or [QrCode.net](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/) and make the image yourself.

You can find many more information on [this QR Code White Book](http://www.unitaglive.com/a/Ten_Commandments_of_QR_Code).

Comment: Thx, I will have a try.